# How to Generate this kind of text which denotes the image as text

Tags: html, text, graphics

There are many websites which does like this, who make their own graphic-like image. But I was wondering how they do it.

See screenshot on: http://i.imgur.com/zVYEkF1.png

```
    o o     o     +              o
+   +     +             o     +       +
            +
o  +    +        o  +           +        +
     __  __           _           _     _
~_,-|  \/  | __ _ ___| |__   __ _| |__ | | ___
    | |\/| |/ _` / __| '_ \ / _` | '_ \| |/ _ \,-~_,- - - ,
~_,-| |  | | (_| \__ \ | | | (_| | |_) | |  __/    |   /\_/\
    |_|  |_|\__,_|___/_| |_|\__,_|_.__/|_|\___|  ~=|__( ^ .^)
~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,-~_,""   ""
o o     o     +              o
+   +     +             o     +       +
            +
o  +    +        o  +           +        +
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try using _FreeType_

Comment: for graphics to asci there are many approaches most based on brightness tables, look here for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/q/23804827/2521214 if you want just Text then create own font  from characters instead of pixels and use that ... if you want to google then search ASCII-art. also read the start of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214

Comment: @Harry I just Added this Answer [conversion from BW Image to ASCII art](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32861551/2521214) might interest you